# pst-barcode produces PS files which Ghostscript can not read

Tags: pstricks, pst-barcode

Weird problem with [`pst-barcode`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-barcode) package.

TeX file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{minimal}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(.25in,.25in)
\psbarcode{tinyurl.com/b5b6du}{format=micro}{qrcode}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

I am able to generate a PS file using `latex` and `dvips`. No errors or warnings are shown. But the file cannot be read by Ghostscript (v. 9.10). The error message is shown.  After a lot of messages like:

```
Unknown in Prolog section at line 2346:
%% end
```

I see the final error message:

```
GPL Ghostscript 9.10 (2013-08-30)
Copyright (C) 2013 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This*emphasized text* software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
Displaying DSC file /home/vit/work/Year2014/qrcodes.ps
Displaying page 1
WM_GSTEXTINDEX not implemented
Error: /rangecheck in --get--
Operand stack:
   18   --nostringval--   4
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1900   1   3   %oparray_pop   1899   1   3   %oparray_pop   1883   1   3   %oparray_pop   1771   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   %loop_continue   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1174/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:117/200(L)--   --dict:174/300(L)--   --dict:38/200(L)--   --dict:110/200(L)--   --dict:33/40(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: No such file or directory

--- Begin offending input ---
%%Page: 1 1
TeXDict begin 1 0 bop 0 TeXcolorgray Black 0 0 a
tx@Dict begin  gsave STV CP T /ps@rot 0 def grestore  end
 0 0
a 0 0 a
tx@Dict begin  gsave STV CP T /ps@refangle 0.  def grestore  end
 0 0 a 0 TeXcolorgray 166 150 a @beginspecial
@setspecial
  tx@Dict begin STP newpath 0.8 SLW 0  setgray   gsave 0.  1 1 0.0
 0.0  translate scale rotate 0 0 moveto (tinyurl.com/b5b6du) (format=micro)
/qrcode /uk.co.terryburton.bwipp findresource exec grestore  end

@endspecial 0 TeXcolorgray 0 TeXcolorgray
eop end

--- End offending input ---
file offset = 0
gsapi_run_string_continue returns -101
```

Regular barcodes are generated without any issues. The problem starts to occur when I add `format=micro` specifier.

> `barcode.sty`: `\ProvidesPackage{pst-barcode}[2012/11/16 package
>   wrapper ... ]`

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Yeah, who can find that duplicate now? .....

Answer (score 3):

`format=micro` handles only 15 alphanumerical characters. use the default `format=full` or delete this option which is the same. See tabular on:

http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR-Code#Micro-QR-Code

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did not know about this limitation.That's pity that no error or warning message is shown by the package.